# Ajax call to net 7 project not working when sending json

Tags: jquery, ajax, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a ajax call in my MVC project which calls a net core 7 controller. When I try sending json to the controller, accountId is null in the controller. Using Object() is a work around but I wanted to use json.

Controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public JsonResult GetAccount(string accountId)
{ ... }
```

Ajax that works:

```
var myObject = new Object();

myObject.accountId = "123";

// Perform the remote call.
$.ajax({
  url: 'ManageUsers/GetAccount',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json;',
  data: myObject,
});
```

Ajax that doesn't work:

```
var requestData = JSON.stringify(`
{`
accountId: "123"`
`});  

$.ajax({
  url: 'ManageUsers/GetAccount',
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json',
  contentType: 'application/json;',
  data: requestData ,
});
```

I have tried different combination in controller. `[FromBody]` or `[FromQuery]` doesn't work. Also tried returning `ActionResult` instead of `JsonResult` which doesn't affect anything.

**I've also noticed if I change the type to POST and change the controller to HttpPost, accountId is null.**

Comment: I've had a go at tiding your code, but either you or SO have added extra backticks (`) where they don't appear to belong.  Can you [edit] so that it matches your actual code.

Comment: If you want to pass JSON to a single string parameter, then you could do:  `data: { accountId: JSON.stringify(yourobject) }` and send as default/x-form, then your "accountId" string parameter would receive a JSON string.  (I don't think this is what you want, hence a comment, not an answer)

Answer (score 0):

you have to decide what do you need. Http Get doesn't work with json, so change action attribute to post

```
[HttpPost]
public JsonResult GetAccount([FromBody] Account account)
{ 
var accountId=account.AccountId;
... 
}
```

and create a class

```
public class Account
{
public string AccountId {get; set;}
}
```

and change Get to Post

```
$.ajax({
  ...
  type: 'POST',
   ...
```

but imho it is better to use get, but  to fix an ajax url

```
var accountId: "123";

$.ajax({
  url: 'ManageUsers/GetAccount?accountId='+ accountId,
  type: 'GET',
  dataType: 'json'
  ....
});
```